# Using boost::chrono::system_clock to get time causes linker error

Tags: c++, boost, clang, c++14, c++-chrono

I have program which is linking to system,chrono and thread in boost. But simply adding `auto now = boost::chrono::system_clock::now()` gives me a linker error.

Following is my **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   boost::circular_buffer<int> test_ring;
   test_ring.resize(10);
   std::cout << "Boost ring size is" << test_ring.size() << std::endl;
   
   // Below line of code causes linker error while I am well able to use boost componenets as you can see above
   auto now = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
   return 0;
}
```

Following is my **CMakelists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(TestProgram)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system chrono thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(TestProgram TestProgram.cpp)
```

I get the following **linker error**:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::chrono::system_clock::now()", referenced from:
      _main in TestProgram.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [TestProgram] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestProgram.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any boost components to link to? As you can see, I am able to link to other Boost components like `boost/circular_buffer` on my machine, it is just that `boost::chrono::system_clock` does not work.

**Environment:**
I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 wiht the following clang compiler.

```
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I'm not good with CMake, but don't you need `target_link_libraries` to actually link with the boost libraries that you found too?

Comment: I updated the code in my question to prove that I am able to link and use a `boost::circular_buffer`. I am also able to use other boost components. It's just that `boost::chrono::system_clock::now` does not work. Strange!

Comment: `circular_buffer` is a header only part of boost. `chrono` is not a header only part of it. So, that explains why the first one works, but the second doesn't

Comment: I have given the complete code. I would be interested to know if this code compiles on someone else's machine.

Comment: The header only library part is a good point! But Boost is installed on my Mac using Brew. All the library binaries should be present. Shouldn't they?

Comment: I'm guessing that you need `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I am missing `target_link_libraries`. Probably all the Boost libraries I have been using earlier were header only. So, it didn't matter?

Comment: Yeah, that must have been it. I actually took your code and managed to reproduce the problem - and fixed it with `target_link_libraries` :-)

Comment: Note: you do not need to use either library from boost, you can use native STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `add_executable`, add `target_link_libraries`:

```
add_executable(TestProgram TestProgram.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestProgram ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```